# Comparison will not work with warning saying range of data type islimited

Tags: c

I keep getting a warning saying that the else if statement is always false due to limited range of data type so i looked it up and still don't understand what i am doing wrong or how to fix it. I am trying to compare input to see if it equals one of several options and don't understand why what i am doing does not work or what to replace it with.

```
int main(int argc,const char *argv[])
{
  FILE *src = input_from_args(argc, argv);
  FILE *dest = stdout;

    if (src == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: unable to open %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if(*(argv[1]) == '-r')
    {
      rot13(src,dest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
else if(*(argv[1]) == '-r')
```

use `""` to specify a string literal (e. g., `"-r"`) and `strcmp` / `strncmp` to compare strings.

`'-r'` is an integer character constant with multiple characters. It has type `int`.

Comment: Dang thanks I mistakenly thought ' and " were interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

In C, we use single quotes for literal chars and double quotes for strings.  *argv[1] is a string and you are comparing it with a literal char '-r'.  Change your code to "-r" and recompile.

Comment: Using "-r" is not enough - you also cannot compare strings using `==`, so that must change, too.

Answer (score 0):

`*(argv[1])` is the same as `argv[1][0]` - a single 8-bit `char`.  I don't know how your compiler is treating `'-r'`, but it can't fit it into a single `char`, so the comparison can never be `true`.